# JUnit not working in Spring Boot with @Autowired annotation

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I have a Spring Boot application in which I'm creating REST web services
using the MVC pattern.

I have a controller, service and DAO class and I use the `@Autowired` annotation for calling methods of the service and DAO layer.

When I create JUnit tests using mockito, the values are going into the controller but from the controller they are not going to the service class.

Here is the code sample:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppplicationConfiguration.class})
public class ExternalControllerTest {


    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;


    @MockBean
    myService myService;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(myController)

                .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testListCluster() throws Exception {


        Input emrInput = new Input();
        emrInput.setId("200004773");
        emrInput.setName("test");

        String expected = "{\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":\"somevalue\"}";

        AutomateRestResponse response = new AutomateRestResponse<JsonObject>();

        response.setMessage("Success");
        response.setStatus("Success");
        response.setData("somevalue");
        Mockito.when(
                externalService.listCluster(emrInput)
        ).thenReturn(response);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/gerData"))


                .andExpect(status().isOk())

                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is("Success")));


        verify(externalService, times(1)).listCluster(emrInput);


        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders

                .post("/v4/listCluster")

                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(emrInputJosn)

                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();


        System.out.println("response body1" + result.getResponse()

                .getContentAsString());
    }`
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: you are trying to create test for which layer?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your post.

Comment: can you try replacing `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you are trying to mock.

Anyway, you should not be able to debug your service/dao that is mocked since what actually executed in the test is the mocked one and not yours.

If you want to test your controller, you can mock your service or dao and define what the response they will return, and then verify that the response you get from your controller is as you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I have an  api(/getdata) input in josn format like this 
{"id": "1","name": "manish","address": "mumbai"}
which give me response  {"status": "success","message", "data": "123455"}.

Comment: how to paste the code, I am not able to paste the code

Comment: WebAppConfiguration
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
ContextConfiguration(classes = {Configuration.class})
public class MyCloudControllerTest {
 

 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 

  

 InjectMocks
    private MyController Controller;

  

 Mock
 MyService externalService;
 
 

 Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                 .standaloneSetup(Controller)
                
                 .build();
 }

Comment: @Test
 public void testMyController() throws Exception {

   
PersonInput personInput = new Person();
personInput .setId("1");
personInput .setName("test");
personInput .setMarker("manish");
personInput .setAddress("mumbai");

String input = "{\"id\": \"1\",\"name\": \"manish\",\"address\": \"mumbai\"}"

String expected = "{"status": "success","message", "data": "123455"}"
AutomateRestResponse response =  new AutomateRestResponse<JsonObject>();
response.setMessage("success");
response.setStatus("status");
response.setData("somevalue");

Comment: please help me in this

Comment: I have added main application.java class above

Answer (score 0):

@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.yourPackage.external" })

public class YourApplication extends org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have pasted, you can do below things:

1. if you are using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` [better change to `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`] then use

   `@MockBean
   private MyService externalService;`

OR

2. use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and

   `@MockBean
   private MyService externalService;`

`@InjectMocks 
 private MyController controller = new MyController(externalService);`

for details checkout :- [testing web in spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Comment: i tried with this also but it is not working . i am pasting my testing class code below. ExternalControllerTest.java

Comment: hi all, please help me in this. I am stuck badly in this

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppplicationConfiguration.class})
public class ExternalControllerTest {


    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController  ;



    @MockBean
    myService myService;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                    .standaloneSetup(myController)

                    .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testListCluster() throws Exception {


Input emrInput = new Input();
emrInput.setId("200004773");
emrInput.setName("test");

String expected = "{\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":\"somevalue\"}";

AutomateRestResponse response =  new AutomateRestResponse<JsonObject>();

response.setMessage("Success");
response.setStatus("Success");
response.setData("somevalue");
Mockito.when(
        externalService.listCluster(emrInput)
                ).thenReturn(response);

mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/gerData"))


.andExpect(status().isOk())



.andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is("Success")));



verify(externalService, times(1)).listCluster(emrInput);



RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders

.post("/v4/listCluster")

.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(emrInputJosn)

.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);



MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();


System.out.println("response body1"+ result.getResponse()

.getContentAsString());
}
}
```

Comment: is this your test class?

Comment: yes, I will input something like this. {"id": "1234", "name": "manish"} and out put I will get "{\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":\"somevalue\"}";

Comment: what you are doing with `.post("/v4/listCluster")`?

Comment: I have an api called /v4/listCluster which is having  http post call and this is  in myController